# Toolkit Listpicker Full mode header template

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-phone-7

I need to create a header in full mode only,but the header is textbox(not a normal header like header="choose item") how can i create a textbox in header should show only in fullexpressionmode.

This is my code,

```
 <ToolKit:ListPicker x:Name="locationpicker"   ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ExpansionMode="FullscreenOnly" ToolTipService.Placement="Top" ToolTipService.ToolTip="LocationName" >
            <ToolKit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Images/location.png" Height="30"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocationName}" ToolTipService.Placement="Right" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Change location"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToolKit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <ToolKit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/Images/map_blue.png"></BitmapImage>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LocationName}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource LocationNameTexBlock}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToolKit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </ToolKit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should Refer this Post: [Customizing ListPicker for WP7 - Part1.](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/customizing-listpicker-for-wp7-part1) It demonstrate how to style the Windows Phone ListPicker and how to customize the different visual states.